# How to add default role to Asp.net identity user manager

Tags: webforms, asp.net-identity

I am new and exploring the Asp.net Identity, I wanted to add a default Role to my users. However, I failed to run this code during runtime and it shows me this error "Role admin does not exist."

```
 var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
 var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
 userManager.AddToRole(user.Id,"admin");
```

I am aware that i didn't created the Role of "admin", Does there any Simplest way to implement this Role based authorization?

Comment: Yeah you use the `if(RoleManager.RoleExists("RoleName")){RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole{Name="RoleName"})}`

Comment: @prospector Appreciate the answer. However, would you mind provide more detail about the RoleManager? I C&P your code, and i got this 
Error "Using the generic type 'RoleManager<TRole, TKey>' requires 2 type arguments". Sorry for the trouble as i am still new to this API

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it should be done, first check if the role exists, and if it doesn't add the role.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {      
       var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
       var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);


       if (result.Succeeded)
            {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));

            }
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Administrator");
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);

    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Notice how the ApplicationDbContext is passed in the method signature.

Comment: This is a solution for MVC, not WebForms

Comment: The code inside the method will be the same regardless.